# how do you fix broken autocomplete and skipped code in event handler

Tags: c#, static, visual-studio-2017, static-methods, eventhandler

[picture of the visual c# properties tab for buttonDealCard_Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezoSm.png)i wanted to create a single object with a method that returned a random card then use it when the button is clicked.
all code shown acts like it dosent exist, autocomplete and auto suggest arent working anymore.

moving the position of the class, whether it was in the same tab, what was static, this fixed the compile time errors.

```cs
 public static class Deck {
  public static Card DealCard() {
   int numberOfCards = 52;
   int r = new Random().Next(0, numberOfCards - 1);
   return new Card(r);
  }
  //...
 }


 private void buttonDealCard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Card newcard = Deck.DealCard();
  MessageBox.Show("newcard");
  userListBox.Items.Add(newcard);
  ...

  //(working code)
 }
```

i expect the output to be a messagebox woth text "newcard" and a random card object to be added to the listbox then working code output.
the actual output  is just the working code output.

after a certain point in my attempts to figure out the problem, nothing i typed would auto suggest or autocomplete, error list would be empty, no "do you want to use an older version to avoid build errors" message, but it acted exactly like before i had written any of this code.

Comment: Where is the code that calls `buttonDealCard_Click` ? Please show that as well.

Comment: ive added the properties window i used, thats the closest i can manage for designer items like buttons